# jQuery gets date inputs wrong after coming back to page

Tags: jquery, date

I have a form on web page and a hidden form and a button. When clicking button the values from visible form are copied into hidden form via jQuery. Then I get values of hidden form inputs via jQuery.

Everything is okay until I go to another page and come back. Then jQuery gets the values of date inputs wrong (though it gets text input values correct).

The question is why it gets the date inputs wrong?

I've created a test-page on my server:

http://163.172.188.95/test

To re-produce:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Page's code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#button").click(
            function () {

            $("input[name='hidden_date']").attr('value', $("input[name='date']").val());
            $("input[name='hidden_text']").attr('value', $("input[name='text']").val());


            $("div").append('<br>', 'form_hidden.serialize(): ', $("#form_hidden").serialize(), '<br>','hidden_date.val() = ', $("[name='hidden_date']").val(), ' hidden_text.val() = ', $("[name='hidden_text']").val(), '<br><br>' );

            }            
        );
    });




</script>

<form id="form_hidden" hidden = "hidden">

    <input type="date" name="hidden_date"/>
    <input type="text" name="hidden_text"/>

</form>

<form id="form">

        <input type="date" name="date"/> <label>date</label><br><br>
        <input type="text" name="text"/> <label>text</label>

</form>


<button id="button">print hidden.serialize()</button><br><br>
<a href="http://www.google.com">link to google.com</a>
<br>
<br>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Try setting value property also using `val()`

Comment: @charlietfl, please be more specific:)

Comment: Setting *value attribute* is not same as setting *value property*. The attribute is generally used by browser on page load to set the property and user edits are not reflected in the attribute

Comment: @charlietfl, yes, that worked:) Though I still don't get why Jquery with attr() is doing good with getting text inputs and not the date ones. But I think your answer can be taken as answer (maybe a little bit more details on attributes and browser?)

Comment: Suggest you read up on how value attribute works